# Debugging Website with JavaScript errors in IE9 - opening debug console fixes the error

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, debugging, internet-explorer-9

I have a website which triggers some JavaScript errors in IE9. When opening the debug-console with F12 and reloading the page, the problem disappears and everything runs just fine. This is clearly annoying and therefore it's difficult to detect the error message in order to solve the problem.

It's a page with a Google Map. Normally, there should be markers on the map. In IE9, there aren't. When opening the console, everything is working.

Does anyone know how to debug this annoyance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In IE, the `console` object is not available unless the console is open. That's what's causing the errors when it's closed. Remove all references to `console` from your code and you should be fine.

Comment: That seems to fix the issue, but it's difficult to close the debug console in IE. Even after a restart of IE and a closed console, it works even without a fix. A restart of the computer should close it though, right?

Comment: I thought just closing the console should be enough, that's odd.